# Xcode Unit Testing - Can't get print commands to display consistently while unit tests running

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, xcode12

I recently started running unit tests on my SwiftUI based app in Xcode version 12.4.

When I run my tests, I can't understand what print commands actually show up in the output vs. which ones don't.

For example, I have this MockRepository class that gets used in testing instead of my normal repository calling Firebase, and I have two print commands in the loadData method. For a while, neither of them were showing up in the output. Now I can get the first command to show output (pretty consistently), but the second one is not showing anything.

I have tried adding breakpoints at that line, but I am still not seeing the output. I also get print commands printing out from a couple of my methods in the actual class being tested, but not from other helper methods.

Is there a good way to consistently tell which print commands will show up in the output and which ones won't (for aiding in debugging)?

Here is my mock repository with the loadData function:

```
//
//  MockActionRepository.swift
//  GoalTogetherTests
//
//  Created by Charlie Page on 3/11/21.
//

import Foundation
@testable import GoalTogether

class MockActionRepository: ObservableObject, ActionStoreType {

    var db = TestDatabase()
    @Published var actions: [Action] = [Action]()
    var actionsPublished: Published<[Action]> { _actions }
    var actionsPublisher: Published<[Action]>.Publisher { $actions }
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        let actionsList = db.actionsCollection
        self.actions = actionsList
        
        print("Here's a new printout I'm going to print")
        print("The actions list third action of: \(self.actions[2].title) has a startDate of \(self.actions[2].startDate)")
    }
    
    func addAction(_ action: Action) {
        self.actions.append(action)
    }
    
    func updateAction(_ action: Action) {
        var actionList = self.actions
        let index = actionList.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == action.id})
        
        guard index != nil else {
            print("Could not find action to update")
            return
        }
        actionList[index!] = action
        
        self.actions = actionList
    }
    
    func deleteAction(_ action: Action) {
        var actionList = self.actions
        
        if let index = actionList.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == action.id}) {
            actionList.remove(at: index)
        }
        self.actions = actionList
    }
}
```

And here are the test methods that call it:

```
//
//  ActionListViewModelTests.swift
//  GoalTogetherTests
//
//  Created by Charlie Page on 3/11/21.
//

import XCTest
@testable import GoalTogether

class ActionListViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: ActionListViewModel!
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        sut = ActionListViewModel(actionRepository: MockActionRepository())
    }
    
    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
    
    func testActionListVM_loadData() {
        // given
        let count = sut.actionRepository.actions.count
        
        // when
        
        // assert
        XCTAssertEqual(count, 3)
    }
    
    func testActionListVM_addAction_canAdd() {
        // given
        let testAction = Action(title: "Test Action specific to the canAdd test.")
        
        // when
        sut.addAction(testAction)
        
        // assert
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.actionRepository.actions.contains(where: { $0.title == testAction.title}))
    }
    
    func testActionListVM_updateAction_canUpdate() {
        // given
        var updatedAction = sut.actionRepository.actions[0]
        
        // when
        updatedAction.title = "New updated action title"
        sut.updateAction(updatedAction)
        
        // assert
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.actionRepository.actions[0].title == "New updated action title")
    }

    func testActionListVM_removeAction_canRemove() {
        // given
        let removalAction = sut.actionRepository.actions[1]
        
        // when
        sut.deleteAction(removalAction)
        let count = sut.actionRepository.actions.count
        
        XCTAssertEqual(count, 2)
    }
    
    func testActionListVM_loadPastActions_hasPastAction() {
        // given
        let pastCount = sut.previousActionCellViewModels.count
        
        // when
        
        // assert
        XCTAssertEqual(pastCount, 1)
    }
    
    func testActionListVM_loadBaseDateActions_hasBaseDateAction() {
        // given
        let currentCount = sut.baseDateActionCellViewModels.count
        
        // when
        
        // assert
        XCTAssertEqual(currentCount, 2)
    }
    
}
```

Here is the first part of my output (I have "All Output" selected), which picks up some of the output, but not all of it:

```
User ID is: Optional("EHOohLd6jMPuLp7CpxtajvYjj2t2")
The current date of 2021-03-30 22:52:12 +0000 is not the end of the week (2021-04-03 22:52:12 +0000)
Start date is 2021-03-31 05:00:00 +0000 and the end of that week is 2021-04-03 05:00:00 +0000
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2021-03-30 17:52:12.662
Test Suite 'GoalTogetherTests.xctest' started at 2021-03-30 17:52:12.663
Test Suite 'ActionListViewModelTests' started at 2021-03-30 17:52:12.663
Test Case '-[GoalTogetherTests.ActionListViewModelTests testActionListVM_addAction_canAdd]' started.
Here's a new printout I'm going to print
The current date of 2021-03-30 22:52:25 +0000 is not the end of the week (2021-04-03 22:52:25 +0000)
Start date is 2021-03-31 05:00:00 +0000 and the end of that week is 2021-04-03 05:00:00 +0000
Test Case '-[GoalTogetherTests.ActionListViewModelTests testActionListVM_addAction_canAdd]' passed (12.570 seconds).
Test Case '-[GoalTogetherTests.ActionListViewModelTests testActionListVM_loadBaseDateActions_hasBaseDateAction]' started.
Here's a new printout I'm going to print
The current date of 2021-03-30 22:52:25 +0000 is not the end of the week (2021-04-03 22:52:25 +0000)
Start date is 2021-03-31 05:00:00 +0000 and the end of that week is 2021-04-03 05:00:00 +0000
Test Case '-[GoalTogetherTests.ActionListViewModelTests testActionListVM_loadBaseDateActions_hasBaseDateAction]' passed (0.172 seconds).
```

Comment: The goal of testing is to assert, not to print.

Comment: One of my tests is failing, possibly because of an issue with one of my helper methods. I'm trying to see what that value is. Should I instead be putting that in an additional assertion in the test. Is that what you're saying?